# pandas dataframe calculate multiple rows based on column ranges and values

Tags: python, pandas

Given: `AB` or `A`(name), `start` and `end` date, how can I find the mean size in a given pandas dataframe (df)?

Example: Give 'A' from `startdate`: 2009-10-04 to `enddate`: 2009-10-06, the result is 19.64 .

```
Idx   Unnamed: 0    Date   Size      
0          AB  2009-10-02  20.03 
1          AB  2009-10-03  19.05
2          AB  2009-10-04  18.89
3          AB  2009-10-05  18.81
4          AB  2009-10-06  19.43
5          A  2009-10-02  19.36
6          A  2009-10-03  19.67
7          A  2009-10-04  19.59
8          A  2009-10-05  19.74
9          A  2009-10-06  19.61
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, this should work for you (answer from WeNYoBen is much elegant though)

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) 
m = (df['Date'] >= '2009-10-04') & (df['Date'] <= '2009-10-06')
name = df['Unnamed:0']=='A'
df[(m)&(name)].groupby('Unnamed:0')['Size'].mean()
```

**Output**

```
A    19.646667
```

You can change the value of mask 'name' to the name you want.

Comment: Thanks! This was a very hard choice for best answer. Extra brownie points for conversion to datetime. I suppose it was my fault that I didn't specify that the Dates column wasn't Date types.

Comment: Important note: This method returns the mean as type pandas.Series!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `.loc`

```
df.loc[df['Unnamed0'].eq('A')&df.Date.between('2009-10-04','2009-10-06'),'Size'].mean()
Out[491]: 19.646666666666665
```